# Building universal app using angular4

Tags: angular

I am using angular cli with universal.

I reffered this link

https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-4-universal-server-side-rendering/

Everything is worked fine.

I need How can i build universal app with cli.

I have no idea.

Kindly advice me,

Thanks

Comment: As of Angular-cli 1.4 Universal support is built in (but still in beta). There is documentation [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering). If you need a working sample project there is [this repo](https://github.com/JayChase/ngx-express-universal).

Answer (score 0):

The sample project **Angular Universal Starter App** provided by Angular is using the Angular CLI

https://github.com/angular/universal-starter

If your project follow this structure, you could build your app like described in the README

> Production (also for testing SSR/Pre-rendering locally)
>
> npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr - Compiles your application and
>   spins up a Node Express to serve your Universal application on
>   http://localhost:4000.
>
> npm run build:prerender && npm run serve:prerender - Compiles your
>   application and prerenders your applications files, spinning up a demo
>   http-server so you can view it on http://localhost:8080 Note: To
>   deploy your static site to a static hosting platform you will have to
>   deploy the dist/browser folder, rather than the usual dist